# How to return different record or value when JOIN relationship returns empty in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

Is it possible to select different (or set default) record if JOIN relationship returns empty in Power BI?

For examples, I have the following three tables:

Date Table:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2023/01 |
| 2023/02 |
| 2023/03 |

Client Table:

| ClientID | ClientDate |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | 2023/01 |
| C2 | 2023/02 |
| C3 | 2023/03 |

SalesRep Table:

| SRID | ClientID |
| --- | --- |
| S1 | C1 |
| S2 | C2 |

If I have a Date slicer and set to 2023/03, the ClientID/SalesRep table visual will have C3 but empty SalesRep. I would like that empty value to default to ClientID, which is C3.

I can accomplish this in SQL by testing the NULL for SRID column after tables are joined. But need to do this in Power BI because data comes from multiple sources.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have the following relationships between your tables:

- `Client Table` and `Date Table` using `ClientDate` and `Date` fields.
- `Client Table` and `SalesRep Table` using `ClientID` fields.

Then in Power Query, create a new query by merging `Client Table` with `SalesRep Table` on the `ClientID` field, if `SRID` is null for any row, fill it with the value from `ClientID` (This can be done using the "Replace Values")
Or using DAX, create a new table a:

```
NewTable =
ADDCOLUMNS(
    'Client Table',
    "SalesRep", 
    COALESCE(
        RELATED('SalesRep Table'[SRID]),
        'Client Table'[ClientID]
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you Amira. Although I didn't use your exact codes, but you pointed me to the right direction and ideas. I created a new table and perform additional columns thru codings. Thanks a lot!